# Embedding controls in controls with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, light

I am building my WPF app with MVVM and am running into a little design stumbling point.  I have a top level window that has some properties that I pass down to my first level of viewmodels and I accomplish that easily enough with the viewmodel constructors.  But if I want to have some usercontrols inside of that level how do I pass information down to them into their view models?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Dependency Property on your child UserControls that you can bind to from you main control.  @Doug Ferguson explained how to do this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424526/dependency-property-in-wpf-silverlight) SO post.  Hope this helps.